# vue page not found after build

Tags: npm, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

i'm having route with

```
    http://localhost:8080/user/reset
```

It work find when i'm in dev
But after build i put dist in localhost

```
    http://localhost/user/reset
```

It says page not found.
But i can access it from home page by clicking on router-link but can't via direct address in my browser.

```
     {
        path: '/user/reset',
        component: function(resolve) {
            require(['@/components/view/reset.vue'], resolve)
        }
    }
```

this is my path in routes.js

Answer (score 2):

I forgot to put .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

for more detail...
https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html